How to avoid period aggregation in Cloudwatch dashboard?
I have a CloudWatch dashboard that is designed to collect logs from a log group associated with a Lambda function. The widgets type is "number", and the Statistic is "Sample count".
I simply need the various widgets on the dashboard to display the number of transactions captured by the filters I've set on the log group. However, the dashboard is currently aggregating the data by "period," which distorts the displayed information.
I need the dashboard to show all the data for the time period that the user wants to see at any given moment, without any aggregation.
I attempted to drop the period definition from the CloudWatch source code, but it didn't work. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if CloudWatch is simply programmed to operate only with certain periods. Additionally, I tried adjusting the dashboard display times in relation to the period to show more accurate data, but this isn’t a viable solution for me. Therefore, I need the dashboard to consistently show the total amount of logs collected within the defined time period, without any aggregations.

If you set your widget period to a minimum (1 second for example) there may be no need for aggregation. I would try this.

From my experience it doesn't help
